# Same question listed twice in the search results

Tags: support, search

Issue:
For the search query 
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=disable+block+cache

The question 
[How to disable caching of a block?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44511/how-to-disable-caching-of-a-block/44576)

is listed twice in the search results as result 1 and result 14.

Result 1

[image: Result 1]

Result 14

[image: Result 14]

What is happening: 
There are some subtle differences even though it links to the same question:

- The last status on them is different, Result 1 refers to asked history whereas Result 14 refers to answered history
- Result 1 indicated there was 1 answer and 1 vote but Result 14 refers to just the vote

What should happen:
Maybe this is how the search is intended to work although listing the same result twice seems counterproductive.

Does this look like a bug or this is how the search is supposed to function?

Comment: Why are you asking about Drupal SE on Meta for Stack Overflow?  But one of those is for the question and the other is for an answer.

Comment: I suppose searching for questions was not built specifically for a particular stack exchange site so if there is a bug it would apply to all Stackexchange sites, atleast that is how efficient programming works. If thats not the case then let me know where to post or feel free to move this.

Comment: (FYI, Stack Exchange-wide problems are best reported either on the  "local" meta (where you saw the issue), or on Meta Stack Exchange (http://meta.stackexchange.com/).)

Answer (score 3):

You are getting results for questions and for answers.

Note the "Q:" and the "A:" - those are *different* posts.

You can constrain for questions only, or answers only using `is:question` or `is:answer`.

Answer (score 3):

Searches return *posts.*  Both questions and answers are posts.  This particular *subject* had both a question and an answer, so it appeared in the search results twice.